# Telerik RadGrid Binder: Bind within HTML Tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, telerik, radgrid

I am currently using Telerik's [RadGrid Binder](http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/developers-guide/deep-dive/client-side-programming/client-binder-controls/radgrid-binder) in an ASP.NET user control to display content on a page. Most of the data-binding works correctly:

```
<sf:DataMemberInfo runat="server" Name="Title" HeaderText='Title'>
    <strong>{{ Title }}</strong>
</sf:DataMemberInfo>
```

However, if I try to bind within an HTML tag, no data-binding takes place:

```
<sf:DataMemberInfo runat="server" Name="ImageUrl" HeaderText='Image'>
    <span><img src='{{ ImageUrl }}' /></span>
</sf:DataMemberInfo>
```

In the above instance, `{{ ImageUrl }}` is literally rendered. Is there some other technique available so that `{{ ImageUrl }}` will data-bind properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the workaround I have done was to hook into the binder's `DataBound` event in JavaScript. Within that event, I access a hidden field where I dump the properly-bound `{{ImageUrl}}` property, and assign the `<img>` tag's `src` attribute to it.